# How to add Inventory sets programatically in Sitecore Commerce

Tags: sitecore-commerce

I am able to add products and associated with Category programmatically. Now I need to add the Inventory sets to its associated products.

Do I need to add the Inventory sets while adding the Sellabale items? Or
do I need to create the Inventory sets after Sellable items are created and just associate the Sellable items with Inventory set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create the inventory set separately and associate it with the sellable 
items. These are the steps I follow:

1. Create an **InventorySet** and associate the inventory set with the
   catalog (You can use the **IAssociateCatalogToInventorySetPipeline**
   pipeline).
2. Create an **InventoryInformation** record. Associate the
   InventoryInformation record with the InventorySet by creating a
   "**InventorySetToInventoryInformation**" relation using the
   **ICreateRelationshipPipeline** pipeline.
3. Retrieve the **SellableItem** and
   add an **InventoryComponent** with an inventoryassociation that points
   to the InventoryInformation entity:

   InventoryAssociations.Add(new InventoryAssociation
                           {
                               InventoryInformation = new EntityReference(id),
                               InventorySet = new EntityReference(inventorySet.Id)
                           }

Comment: any possible to add some sample code here?

Answer (score 0):

There is also a simpler way, just use **AssociateSellableItemToInventorySetPipeline**, you need to run it and provide:

- SellableItem ID
- Variant ID
- Inventory ID
- EntityView (contains basic inventory information like Quantity, etc.)

Example:

```
var sellableItemInventorySetArgument = new SellableItemInventorySetArgument(productId, inventoryId);
sellableItemInventorySetArgument.VariationId = variantId;

var entityView = new EntityView();
entityView.Properties = new List<ViewProperty>();
entityView.Properties.Add(new ViewProperty() { Name = "Quantity", Value = "5" });
sellableItemInventorySetArgument.EntityView = entityView;

associateSellableItemToInventorySetPipeline.Run(sellableItemInventorySetArgument, context);
```